# PHP convert string object into JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I convert this

```
$shipmentDet = '{"{\"Coupon\": \"\", \"PromotionName\": \"FREE Tighty Wifey\", \"DiscountAmount\": 23.75}","{\"Coupon\": \"get20\", \"PromotionName\": \"GET20\", \"DiscountAmount\": 20}"}'
```

I need to convert the string object into JSON array using PHP.

I have used the json_decode() but, it does not work properly

```
$shipmentRec = (array)json_decode($shipmentDet, true);
```

Comment: You cannot decode it because it isn't a valid JSON string. jsonlint.com

Comment: the string you have is badly escaped / malformed as put by @JayBlanchard  you wont be able to decode that string unless it was encoded in right way, try posting the code as to how you got that data in that format may be mistake lies in previous steps.

Comment: after ending ItemCatalogIDOptions json value there is an json error , please check your json once again

Answer (score -1):

$result = json_decode($shipmentDet, true);

Comment: try it and then vardump result

Comment: Exactly, please do that.